# Проблема с камерой Hikvision

Tags: ip

[image: Если нужно что-то еще пишите в комменты][[image: Сама камера][1]]При авторизации через вэбморду блокируется и просит перезайти через 30 мин. через 30 мин происходит тоже самое.

Comment: Обратитесь в техподдержку Hikvision

Comment: Обращался, время ответа слишком долгое, а проблему с подключением требуют решить в ближайшие сроки

Comment: ЕМНИП пароль через вебморду и по ONVIF - они разные...

Comment: у тебя включена блокировка нелегального входа в настройках, если добавлена камера с неправильным паролем в систему видеонаблюдения то будет блокироваться до ребута камеры автоматом. Если совсем залочилась, то у камеры внутри кнопка сброса есть, нажми ее подай питание, настройки слетят, запусти SADP задай по новой пароль и настрой повторно.

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло!

Answer (score 1):

**"Yakov"**
у тебя включена блокировка нелегального входа в настройках, если добавлена камера с неправильным паролем в систему видеонаблюдения то будет блокироваться до ребута камеры автоматом. Если совсем залочилась, то у камеры внутри кнопка сброса есть, нажми ее подай питание, настройки слетят, запусти SADP задай по новой пароль и настрой повторно.